# i wonderd how google search engine pick results with no time

Tags: mysql, google-search

can any one give an idea how google pick search results with no time(80ms to 100ms).

Iam using mysql as my db if it has data with 30lakes rows in it, even though it has proper indexing and references it tooks more time to load.

Can any one explain how google search engine works.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: They got some kickass servers ^^.

Comment: Hii, even though its veryyy late to answer your question, i found a site explaining how gooogle search works...
Here is the link...

http://www.google.co.in/insidesearch/howsearchworks/thestory/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a read of the original documents, [The Anatomy of a Large-Scale Hypertextual Web Search Engine](http://The%20Anatomy%20of%20a%20Large-Scale%20Hypertextual%20Web%20Search%20Engine).

> In this paper, we present Google, a prototype of a large-scale search engine which makes heavy use of the structure present in hypertext. Google is designed to crawl and index the Web efficiently and produce much more satisfying search results than existing systems. The prototype with a full text and hyperlink database of at least 24 million pages is available at http://google.stanford.edu/
>
> To engineer a search engine is a challenging task. Search engines index tens to hundreds of millions of web pages involving a comparable number of distinct terms. They answer tens of millions of queries every day. Despite the importance of large-scale search engines on the web, very little academic research has been done on them. Furthermore, due to rapid advance in technology and web proliferation, creating a web search engine today is very different from three years ago. This paper provides an in-depth description of our large-scale web search engine -- the first such detailed public description we know of to date.
>
> Apart from the problems of scaling traditional search techniques to data of this magnitude, there are new technical challenges involved with using the additional information present in hypertext to produce better search results. This paper addresses this question of how to build a practical large-scale system which can exploit the additional information present in hypertext. Also we look at the problem of how to effectively deal with uncontrolled hypertext collections where anyone can publish anything they want.

It's obviously come a long way since then, but that should give you a start :)

Answer (score 3):

This might be helpful to you

```
http://www.googleguide.com/google_works.html
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a (rough) overview of Google's server structure:

http://www.googleguide.com/google_works.html

In a nutshell, Google does not have a single MySQL server in the backend but several servers of various (common and proprietary) systems.

Answer (score 0):

Google has about 1000 servers in one country. When you press enter, the query is sent to as many of the servers as possible and then they all search a certain amount of their search database, and then they put their results together and send them to your computer.

More information is available in a book called *The Google Story*. I don't have it with me at the moment, so I can't find out the author.

Ad@m